# Given a probability triple $(\Omega,\mathbf{F},P)$ where $\Omega=[0,1]$, why must $\mathbf{F}$ contain all the intervals?

Tags: probability-theory

Given a probability triple $(\Omega,\mathbf{F},P)$ where $\Omega=[0,1]$, why must $\mathbf{F}$ contain all the intervals?

I am reading "A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory" by Jeffrey S. Rosenthal and in section $2$ he discusses probability triples/probability space. There he mentions that if we were to define a probability triple $(\Omega,\mathbf{F},P)$ on an uncountable set say $\Omega=[0,1]$ which corresponds to the Uniform distribution $[0,1]$ then we certainly can't take all the subsets of $\Omega$ (as proved in a proposition given in section 1). I understand his point up until here. But he then says that it must be the case that $\mathbf{F}$ contains all the intervals, whereby intervals he means all the open, closes, half-open/singleton and empty intervals.

I know that the set of all intervals $J$ does not form a sigma-algebra because it is not closed under unions, but why must it be contained in $\mathbf{F}$ is something that I do not quite understand.

Comment: Well, what does it mean for a probability triple to correspond to a uniform distribution?

Comment: was my answer below helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's not the case that any sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}$ would have to contain all the intervals (as you described). This is because the exact structure of $[0,1]$ need not be reflected in every probability triple - all that matters is that $[0,1]$ is an uncountable set. A little more precisely, you could, for example, take any bijection $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ and then form $\mathcal{F}$ based on the "intervals" $f((a,b))$ for any $(a,b) \subseteq [0,1]$. *However*, the point of the uniform distribution is to get a natural probability triple compatible with the nice ordering of $[0,1]$. We want the probability of $(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})$ to be $\frac{1}{3}$, etc.